# 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm just experimenting with EF Core and SQLite and have been slightly stumped by the issue.

If I attempt to configure the database like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Filename=./App_Data/dashboard.db") );
```

And then execute:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c MyDbContext
```

I get:

> 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext'

But if I do this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./App_Data/dashboard.db");
}
```

All works as expected.

My context is setup to work with the fluent interface:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) 
    : base(options)
{
}

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

It seems from various articles that others have the fluent approach working fine.

Have anyone else had this issue and solved in using Core 2.1.0?

Comment: is your dbcontext in the main web app or in a separate class library?

Comment: It's in the main application.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a design time db context factory to your project like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace yournamespace
{
    public class YourDbContextDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
    {
        public YourDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>();
            builder.UseSqlite("Data Source=somename.db");

            return new YourDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think the connection string has to be correct, EF will use this to create the context when generating the migration